# Why is my weight painting not following brush strokes, when trying to paint for a vertex group on a plane

Tags: particles, weight-painting

i want to make a plane with grass using particle system. For that i start with a plane, create a vertex group and go to weight paint mode to paint the areas where i want grass. But for some reason, the weight painting does not follow my brush across the plane. Mostly the brush does nothing on the plane, but when i just try to paint crazily all across the plane, ,i get few paint values on the sides of the plane. Please help.

File attached -
https://easyupload.io/fz1i3e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you haven't subdivided your plane at all. You can only paint on vertices. Since your plane has only four, you hardly can see your paintings.

Select your plane, Tab -> edit mode, right click on plane -> subdivide -> enter 20 and try again.

[image]

Comment: ohhhh, thanks for the answer, i get it now. :D

Comment: you are welcome